Roblox Studio Lua: Variable changing without being referenced
This is my module script:
local phases = {}

local function getRoleAssignments(playersToAssignRoles, roles)
     --Assigns a random player to each role then removes player from list so player can't get two roles.
     --Not every role will be assigned if not enough players
    for role, _ in pairs(roles) do
        local player = nil

        if 0 < #playersToAssignRoles then
            player = playersToAssignRoles[math.random(1,#playersToAssignRoles)]
        end

        roles[role] = player
        table.remove(playersToAssignRoles,table.find(playersToAssignRoles,player))
    end

    return roles
end


function phases.loadGame(players, roles)
    local map = getRandomMap()
    print(players) --Prints a full table (just one player because just me testing)
    local roleAssignments = getRoleAssignments(players, roles)
    print(players) --Prints an empty table
end 

This is how I've implemented it in my main script.
local playersPlaying = Players:GetPlayers()
roles = Phases.loadGame(playersPlaying, roles)

The players table became empty after calling getRoleAssignments(players, roles) even though I have not referenced it at all. I have only passed it into the function, which should create a local copy as stated in the docs. However, the players table is empty after I called the function shown by the print statement when ran.
I expect the players table to retain its data.
I've tried to making sure the identifiers are not the same which did not work.
I've tired storing the players table in a separate local variable and passing that into the function instead, it did not work.
Not calling the function does result in the players table retain its data though.

it appears that lua just gives a pointer to the table location instead of giving a copy.
https://onecompiler.com/lua/42e9nrkup
a way to fix this could be by copying the table yourself by doing:
local copy = table.pack(table.unpack(playersToAssignRoles))


Why has it passed a pointer?

@boombuster2000 because that is how Lua, and most languages pass an object around, for numbers and strings it is trivial to copy but a table could have all sorts of edge cases, like how deep the copy should be.

@Nifim but in the other where I've passed a table, it has been copied instead of passing a pointer. Is there a certain scenario it will pass a pointer?
